# Printing arabic characters with GDI+ results in scrambled output with Microsoft XPS Document Writer

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, gdi+, arabic-support

I need to use GDI+ methods to print arabic characters and I'm encountering some issues which seem to be related to the specific printer.

This is the method that I'm using in my Windows application:

```
g.DrawString("اللائحة (EC) رقم 648/2004 (المنظفات)", new Font("Arial Unicode MS", 5), Brushes.Black, rectangle, new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft));
```

*g* is the printer graphics object and *rectangle* is the printing area.

I'm trying it in Windows 10 with the default installed printers **Microsoft Print to PDF** and **Microsoft XPS Document Writer**.

This is the correct output with **Microsoft Print to PDF**:

[image]

This is the output from **Microsoft XPS Document Writer**:

[image]

As you can see all characters are scrambled!

Do you know why is this happening? Is there something that I can do to print correctly arabic characters with GDI+ to all printers?

Comment: It is not likely that this has anything to do with Graphics.DrawString() or the XPS document writer.  Much more likely that it is an issue with the XPS viewer.  Mixing Arabic with Latin glyphs and punctuation is rarely not a problem, consider giving the text renderer explicit hints about the intended direction.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark

Comment: I have already passed in the `StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft` and it seems working with all printers except the XPS one. My program is using the XPS Document Writer to make the default preview of the documents, so that's why I need to make it working...

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to reproduce, never mind solve, your problem. That said, it looks like you may not be taking into account right-to-left vs. left-to-right characters. They will appear left-to-right in your code editor, but right-to-left scripts are handled correctly during actual rendering and so may overlap left-to-right scripts if you don't account for that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I can confirm the problem. The complex text (containing both English and Arabic letters) prints correctly using Microsoft Print to PDF and also you can see the result correctly in Print Preview Dialog, but using Microsoft XPS Document Writer the result is not printed correctly.  While the code is not a good example of MCVE, but it helps you to simply reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just for those who may have some idea on the problem, I'll share these two observations: **1)** If you use `TextRenderer.DrawText` you can get the result correctly. But its [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h60yx8s5(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_2) that *is not supported for printing from Windows Forms. Instead, use the DrawString methods of the Graphics class.* **2)** The problem seems to be more related to XPS Viewer, because if you print the same زluttered XPS fale to a PDF printer, you see the result is correct in PDF.

Comment: Update: applying a rotation to the graphics before the `DrawString` method results in a correct output: `g.RotateTransform(0.1f);` (in this case it is a "fake" small rotation). It seems a bug in the XPS Document Writer...